# Android EditText issue findviewbyId

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-widget

Assigning ids to few edit texts results in the following error :

```
the error is in the parameters of findViewById token
```

Here is the line of code that its on

```
final EditText myEditField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.percentText1);
```

...This is the Xml code sorry again to nerd for posting the java...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/percentText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/enterButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="224dp"
        android:onClick="onEnterClick"
        android:text="Calculate Tip" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/percentText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Percent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/percentage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/percentText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Bill Amount" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

...The Java Code... The error i figure is that i improperly gave the edit text an id...

```
package tip.calculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import tip.calculator.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        EditText myEditField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.percentText); //error here 


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onEnterClick(String args []){


        int percentage;
        int percentageInp;
        int billAmount;
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you post your XML layout? Need to make sure you're setting the id correctly.

Comment: Please add your xml file. There might be a chance where you actually just copy pasted some Edit Text's and forgot to change there id's.

Comment: i just left clicked them in outline view and pressed change id, was i supposed to do it im my xml?? If so could you tell me how?? thanks

Comment: At the bottom there should be a tab that says "Graphical Layout", thats what you are on now, you want the tab that says "my_layout.xml" where "my_layout" is actually the name of your layout. That said, after re-reading your post, I think @Nerd might be right, you have the wrong import as it doesn't sound like the error you are getting is when you run the app, but rather in Eclipse as a complication error.

Comment: just check what I have listed below.  I think you will find that if you specify the id as I have indicated in the layout and you also have resolved all errors in res directory. You are good to go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you dont have this in your imports

```
import android.R;
```

Eclipse sometimes imports this class which instead should be

```
import your.application.packagename.R;
```

usually this happens when we `ctrl+shft+o` to fix imports. Eclipse adds the `R` class when we do that. :)

**EDIT:**

from your new question, there is a spelling error. 
Try to paste this line inside the onCreate() method:

```
EditText myEditField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.percentText);
```

Comment: i didn't have it in my imports so i added the second class, but nothing changed

Comment: ok i posted edit2 into onCreate();, but i get the same error i am pretty sure i declared the id wrong...

Comment: try cleaning the project: Eclipse->Project>Clean

Answer (score 1):

change

```
final EditText myEditField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.percentText1);
```

to

```
final EditText myEditField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.percentText);
```

percentText1 is the id for RelativeLayout not for EditText.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to understand is that if there is any problem with a resource nothing than nothing works anywhere.  So check if the there are any errors in the resource folder? Are there any problems listed? Then just attempt to find one of buttons, comment everything else out.  You will not find anything until you resolve all the layout errors.  Then just make sure you are declaring the id like this

```
  android:id="@+id/myTextId"
```

Comment: i would put this under the editText portion of the layout xml file right>

Answer (score 0):

import tip.calculator.R; <- there it's the problem i think